# Looking for a way to Auto press a button on a web-page every X minutes

Tags: browser, page-refresh

I have a specific Web-Page that we use in my work, that doesn't have an auto refresh option and i have to manually press a button in the page.
Is there a way with an extension (in any browser) or with some coding (?) to make the page to press a button in every X minutes?

Answer (score 3):

Various plugins can be used for browser automation, the most popular one is [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en).

Your workflow could be automated by following these steps:

1. Install [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en)
2. Add a new script by going to the domain and clicking "Create a new script...":
   [image: This button]

   3. Insert the following scripts, this clicks the button every x miliseconds.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var delayInMiliseconds = 1000;
    var button = document.querySelector('#my-button');

    setInterval(function(){
        button.click();
    }, delayInMiliseconds);
})();
```

Comment: After a couple of tries i managed to write the code correctly and save it in the TamperMonkey. I choose the webpage i wish to run it, and with the Inspect Element i found the button ID.
put after the time i choose passes nothing happens.

Comment: Could you add a `console.log('test')` to the script and confirm that `test` is outputted to the browser console? @Fitsou

Comment: I changed the text with a more friendly to me key word. and i found it in the console in line 26 (if that helps)
```console.log('Nick')```

Comment: Does the id change on page refresh? @Fitsou

Comment: Could you try the following selector: `var button = document.querySelector('[id*="SearchButton_C"]')` @Fitsou

Comment: No the id does not change on page refresh.
I did change it according to your latest comment but still it doesn't work.

Comment: have you had the change to see it?

Answer (score 0):

Given you have a button `<button id="myButtonId" ...>Refresh</button>` on your page you can add the following script to the page:

```
<script>
    setInterval(function () {
        document.getElementById("myButtonId").click();
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

Here 5000 is interval length in milliseconds.